# Web service error serialize member

Tags: asp.net, web-services, serialization

I want to ask about web service, when I ran my web service
I didn't get error when I debug it, but when I run it,
I get this error on my browser:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot serialize member System.Web.UI.Control.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

I have google it, but I don't get my answer. Even I have use another System.Web.UI, it still same
Someone help me please

Anyway, this is my web service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Rabbitry
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class KaryawanWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public RabbitryDB _db = new RabbitryDB();

        [WebMethod] // get all employee data
        public Karyawan[] GetAllKaryawan()
        {
            return _db.Karyawans.ToArray();
        }

        [WebMethod] //get employee data by ID
        public Karyawan GetKaryawanByID(string NIK)
        {
            return _db.Karyawans.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NIK == NIK);
        }

        [WebMethod] // inserting new employee
        public void TambahKaryawan(string NIK, string ktpKaryawan, string namaKaryawan, string alamatKaryawan, 
                                    string telpKaryawan, string hpKaryawan, string joinKaryawan, string statusKaryawan,
                                    string pwd, string role)
        {
            DateTime join;
            bool rol, status;

            DateTime.TryParse(joinKaryawan, out join);
            bool.TryParse(role, out rol);
            bool.TryParse(statusKaryawan, out status);

            Karyawan k = new Karyawan
            {
                NIK = NIK,
                ktpKaryawan = ktpKaryawan,
                namaKaryawan = namaKaryawan,
                alamatKaryawan = alamatKaryawan,
                telpKaryawan = telpKaryawan,
                hpKaryawan = hpKaryawan,
                joinKaryawan = join,
                statusKaryawan = status
            };

            Login l = new Login
            {
                NIK = NIK,
                Password = pwd,
                role = rol
            };

            _db.Karyawans.InsertOnSubmit(k);
            _db.Logins.InsertOnSubmit(l);
            _db.SubmitChanges();
        }

        [WebMethod] //edit employee data
        public void EditKaryawan(string NIK, string alamatKaryawan,
                                    string telpKaryawan, string hpKaryawan, string statusKaryawan)
        {
            bool status;
            bool.TryParse(statusKaryawan, out status);

            Karyawan k = _db.Karyawans.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NIK == NIK);
            if (k != null)
            {
                k.alamatKaryawan = alamatKaryawan;
                k.telpKaryawan = telpKaryawan;
                k.hpKaryawan = hpKaryawan;
                k.statusKaryawan = status;
                _db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }


        [WebMethod] //deleting emplyee data
        public void HapusKaryawan(string NIK)
        {
            Karyawan k = _db.Karyawans.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NIK == NIK);
            Login l = _db.Logins.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NIK == NIK);
            if (k != null)
            {
                _db.Logins.DeleteOnSubmit(l);
                _db.Karyawans.DeleteOnSubmit(k);
                _db.SubmitChanges();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please delete all of that code and replace it with only the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: done...
i think maybe You need the code so I copy it all..

Comment: No way I'm reading all of that. Please try to narrow the problem down. Don't just post your entire application and expect someone to figure it all out for you.

Comment: Well, I just create a web service for my application, then I made it. When I want to test the web service, normally it run in the browser and I can test it. I have try to create a new WS and it's fine, nothing problem. What I want to ask is, why I get the error code because when I debug it, it said no error. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not going to do your job for you without getting paid for it. Narrow down the problem to a smaller region of code, then post the smaller example.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want people doing my job, I just wondering what happened to my WS, because all of my WS got that error (Cannot serialize member System.Web.UI.Control.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface) and I don't get it, why.. because if i made a hello world WS, it run normally, i just don't understand about this error.. sorry for any mistaken/misspeling, my English is bad

Comment: It's done John, the answer is in my DBML, about parent and child property. Thanks for Your respond.

Comment: I still don't know if you understand. The problem is that something that you are attempting to serialize contains a member of type `ISite`. `ISite` is an interface, and you cannot serialize an interface. You are probably trying to serialize something that derives from `Component` or `IComponent`.

Comment: hello John, this problem has been solved.. The problem is in child and parent property on my DBML.. thanks for Your answer, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm already done this thing

the problem is in the DBML name
the name of the table couldn't be ended by S so I change from Kamus to Kamu and it works well